# Combinations of English letters that are an English word out of 10,000 possible combinations

Tags: r, combinations, computation

I have a tibble of 10000 letters made from 4 vectors. I made the tibble using the crossing function in tidyr, which gave me all possible 4-letter combinations. I want to find the ones that are English words, so I think it needs to read an English dictionary to find all 4-letter combinations that are a word in English.

I've searched Google.

```
library (tidyr)
a <- c('s', 'd', 'r',' h', 't', 'f', 'b', 'l', 'p', 'm')
b <- c('l', 'e', 'h', 'r', 'y', 'n', 'u', 'a', 'i', 'o')
c <- c('k', 'o', 'a', 't', 'e', 'l', 'n', 'i', 'r', 's')
d <- c('a', 'n', 't', 'e', 'p', 'y', 'l', 'd', 's', 'k')

lock <- crossing (a,b,c,d)
```

glimpse (lock)
Observations: 10,000
Variables: 4

I want a list of combinations that are English that I can examine.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
library(dplyr)
library(qdapDictionaries)
df <-  crossing (a,b,c,d) %>%
        mutate(x=paste(a,b,c,d, sep="")) %>%
        filter(x %in% GradyAugmented)
```

You can obviously replace `GradyAugmented` by any other wordlist in `qdapDictionaries` (pull up `?qdapDictionaries` to see full list) or you can replace it with a list from any other package/custom list.

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  a     b     c     d     x    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 b     a     a     l     baal 
2 b     a     a     s     baas 
3 b     a     i     l     bail 
4 b     a     i     t     bait 
5 b     a     k     e     bake 
6 b     a     l     d     bald
```

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to open a wordlock bike lock that I bought years ago and can't remember the combination.